# How to call two webservices in a single method call in Java without browser?

Tags: java, web-services

I have a method which has two different web service like `getInt` and `getString`. Is it possible to call these two web service in my single Java method?

And also I want to do this in Java code and not on the browser. Firstly, I want to know how to create a client in Java and then run these services.

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: in my project i want to achieve this...So that

Comment: I'm deducing that you don't have a lot of experience, so you have a lot to read and learn. This question is too broad and a bit unclear.

Comment: why don't you just try it?

Comment: Why not create a single web service which has multiple behaviors?  It could run one or two parts depending on a variable which is passed into it.

Comment: Yeah I'm new to java and webservices @ Kayaman. Perhaps I wanted to do this in our project.

Answer (score 0):

you only  need to invoke the getString and getInt in your java method.
if you want to use jave code call those services, you should use Jmock